# Чат между командной строкой и терминалом

Tags: terminal, сеть, cmd, java, чат

Всем привет!
Возникла идея реализовать чат без GUI, а с использованием терминала Mac OS X и командной строки Windows; 2 разные машины и одна сеть.
В принципе, думаю, ничего сложного не должно быть: настраиваем сеть между машинами, запускаем программы в terminal и cmd, настраиваем имена, вводим сообщения и выводим саму переписку. Ну и, соответственно, радуемся, что получилось :)
НО... есть сомнения на счет там всяких фаерволов и прочего.
Поэтому, хотел спросить у знающих.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вы уже код хоть какой то написали? или пока боитесь? Главный совет - перестать ныть и начать писать код.

Comment: > Поэтому, хотел спросить у знающих.

Спросите, вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: в хр было net send =)

Comment: @KoVadim, кто здесь ныл? Я что просил все сделать за меня? 
В общем, я отвечу - да хоть какой то на Swing написали, хоть как то и работает. Теперь захотелось через терминал.
Думаю, вам бы следовало поучиться отвечать у пользователя @VladD - человек без агрессии все объяснил.

Comment: @SuperHuman пользователь @VladD просто покапитанил. 

Задавая вопросы, всегда уточняйте, что уже сделали, иначе ответы всегда будут "агрессивными".

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо за советы. 
Но, я лишь спросил реально ли это и хотел услышать о возможных трудностях в реализации. Зачем мне говорить что уже сделал? Если возникнут вопросы, я задам. И не надо быть "мамочкой".

Comment: что бы понять возможные Ваши трудности, нужно узнать, что Вы уже сделали. Судя с Вашего вопроса - ничего. Откуда я знаю, может там с `if`-ами возникнет проблема.

А "мамочка" из меня не получится, если Вы понимаете о чем я говорю:)

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чат в командной строке ничем не отличается от графического. Вам всё равно нужно установить соединение, всё равно нужны нотификации о новом сообщении, всё равно нужен формат передачи информации. Различается лишь фронтэнд.

Поэтому никаких особенных отличий нету. Пишите бэкэнд для начала.

Comment: Спасибо!
Единственный нормальный и приемлемый ответ!